# I am not able to see the value updated that I insert manually

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement an onChange method that when the user type something it gets updated in real time and displayed in the div. The component that I am talking about is at the end of the code and it's called  and it is an input that will be rendered 4 times on the dom. For a reason no value get shown on the div I mean {this.state.stake}. Could anyone help me in fixing that? Thanks

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Stake from './stake';

class FetchRandomBet extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            bet: null,
            value: this.props.value,
            stake: ''
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://localhost:4000/";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();

        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            bet: data.bets,
        });
    }

    changeStake = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            stake: [e.target.value]
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { valueProp: value } = this.props;
        const { bet, loading } = this.state;

        if (loading) {
            return <div>loading..</div>;
        }
        if (!bet) {
            return <div>did not get data</div>;
        }
        return (
            < div >
                {
                    loading || !bet ? (
                        <div>loading..</div>
                    ) : value === 0 ? (
                        <div className="bet-list">
                            <ol>
                                <p>NAME</p>
                                {
                                    bet.map(post => (
                                        <li key={post.id}>
                                            {post.name}
                                        </li>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </ol>
                            <ul>
                                <p>ODDS</p>
                                {
                                    bet.map(post => (
                                        <li key={post.id}>
                                            {post.odds[4].oddsDecimal}
                                            <div className="stake-margin">
                                                <Stake
                                                    onChange={this.changeStake} />
                                                {this.state.stake}
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass this.state.stake as a prop of Stake component.

```
<Stake 
   onChange={this.changeStake}
   stake={this.state.stake}
/>
```

Then inside of the Stake component assign stake prop to value on an the input. It would look something like this.

```
const Stake =({stake, onChange})=>{
   
  return <input value={stake} onChange={onChange} />
}
```